# React JS - value from Search component in Semantic UI is an object reference, not a value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, semantic-ui

I'm trying to improve my somewhat awkward search implementation in a React JS app to use Semantic UI's search component.

The current search logic is based on a button-push, which reads the text entered into an adjacent text-box and conducts the search based on that. Here's the bare-bones of that implementation:

```
  constructor(props) {

    super(props);
    const {cookies} = props;


    this.state = {

      word: '',
      newWord: '',
      licenses: [],
      licensePage: [],
      csrfToken: cookies.get('XSRF-TOKEN'), 
      isLoading: true,
      licensesPerPage: 7,
      activePage: 1,
      begin: 0,
      end: 7
    };

    this.remove = this.remove.bind(this);
    this.btnClick = this.btnClick.bind(this);

  }
```

...

```
   async searchFromString () {

     this.setState({isLoading: true});

     fetch(`api/license/search/${this.props.searchString}`, {
        credentials: 'include'})
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => this.setState({
          licenses: data,
          isLoading: false,
          licensePage: data.slice(this.state.begin, this.state.end)

        }))
        .catch(() => this.props.history.push('/'));
    }
```

...

```
 render() {
    const {licensePage, activePage } = this.state;
    const {licenses, isLoading, licensesPerPage} = this.state;
    const totalPages = Math.ceil(licenses.length / licensesPerPage);

    if (isLoading) {
      return <p>Loading...</p>;
    }

      const licenseList = licensePage.map(license => {
      return<tr key={license.id}>
        <td style={{whiteSpace: 'nowrap'}}>{license.fullName}</td>
        <td style={{whiteSpace: 'nowrap'}}>{license.requester}</td>
        <td style={{whiteSpace: 'nowrap'}}>{license.tag}</td>
        <td style={{whiteSpace: 'nowrap'}}>{license.dateCreated.substring(0, 10)}</td>
        <td style={{whiteSpace: 'nowrap'}}>{license.expiration}</td>
        <td style={{whiteSpace: 'nowrap'}}>{license.systems}</td>
        <td>

        <ButtonGroup>
            <Button size="sm" color="primary" tag={Link} to={"/licenses/" + license.id}>Edit</Button>
            <Button size="sm" color="dark" onClick={() => this.download(license.url)}>Download</Button>
            <Button size="sm" color="danger" onClick={() => this.remove(license.id)}>Delete</Button>
        </ButtonGroup>

        </td>
      </tr>
    });
```

I've added the Semantic Search component as follows:

```
  async handleSearchChangeNew (value) {

         this.props.updateSearchString(value);
    
         //this.setState({isLoading: true});
    
         fetch(`api/license/search/${this.props.searchString}`, {
            credentials: 'include'})
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => this.setState({
              licenses: data,
              isLoading: false,
              licensePage: data.slice(this.state.begin, this.state.end)
    
            }))
            .catch(() => this.props.history.push('/'));
        }
```

...

```
          <div>
            <Search
    //                 loading={loading}
    //                 onResultSelect={(e, data) =>
    //                    dispatch({ type: 'UPDATE_SELECTION', selection: data.result.title })
    //                 }
                     onSearchChange={this.handleSearchChangeNew}
    //                 resultRenderer={resultRenderer}
    //                 results={results}
    //                      value={value}
                />
    
               </div>
```

Most of the properties are commented out because their functionality is included in the search method. I've left them in there for reference.

The problem occurs when it makes the call to the backend. Instead of taking the entered value from the search component, it's calling  with an object reference:

```
LicenseList.js:153 GET http://localhost:3000/api/license/search/[object%20Object] 400 (Bad Request)
```

Why the object reference? The search values is being stored in props and referenced in the same way as the current search method.

Comment: Have you tried converting the object to a string with stringify() ? 

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_stringify.asp#:~:text=Stringify%20a%20JavaScript%20Object&text=Use%20the%20JavaScript%20function%20JSON,stringify(obj)%3B

Comment: When I stringify it, the URL looks like this: http://localhost:3000/api/license/search/%22/%22u/%22%22 and returns a 404.

Comment: Jack, I can't access your localhost URL, its running on your local PC. Can you host it on a public server or maybe use a sandbox so that others can view it? A 404 (Not Found) seems to indicate you're using an incorrect URL. Are you sure the API licence is stored on local?

Comment: Hi Ezani, thanks for checking. Yes, it's running on localhost for test. It's deployed to an AWS server in production, but I would have to give you login rights to see it. In any case, I've somewhat gotten around the problem by replace the <div> with <form> and eliminating the <search> button. I still can't use the Semantic-UI search component, but being able to submit the search by pressing enter is definitely an improvement. It also means the clear search resets the search results to the default.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of people made comments to a different post I made around the same problem related to using forms.  Based on that input, I've somewhat gotten around the problem by replacing the  with  and eliminating the  button. I still can't use the Semantic-UI search component, but being able to submit the search by pressing enter is definitely an improvement. It also means the clear search resets the search results to the default.